# What does a "bingo" do?

Tags: pokemon-quest

In Pokemon Quest for Nintendo Switch you can achieve a bingo. When a Pokemon has three slots filled in a row (not on a diagonal) with stones, you get a certain bonus. But *what bonus*? The text explaining the bingo went by way too fast.

A bingo is also indicated by a white Pokeball on the left of the slots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see what the bingo bonus for a Pokémon is, click the magnifying glass button in the top-right of the same screen, to bring up the Pokémon's attributes screen. It is in the bottom middle of this screen.

Comment: Perfect! I never bothered much looking into those detailed stats.